# Why is heat hot?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

In the chapter calorimetry of class 10 I read that heat energy is the total energy content of a body, that is sum of the  kinetic energy of the molecules and their potential energy due to the attractive forces between them.

But why is it that just because a couple of molecules are moving randomly and rapidly they need to be hot?

I mean why they give a sensation of  "HOTNESS" when it is touched.

What is actually the relation between rapid movement and becoming hot?

Also why do the molecules vibrate on heating and the vibration increases on supplying more heat.

Suppose I keep a body at a certain height it will surely possess potential energy but that energy need not make it move vigorously as in the case of molecules.

Would be helpful if somebody could kindly explain my doubts.

Comment: The question of what gives a certain sensation is more about [biology.se] than physics.

Comment: Does it help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature?

Comment: 'Hotness' is a sensation in our brain. It has little to do with physics. A bit like 'smell', 'sound' or 'colour'.

Comment: You should study the functionality of these receptors https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoreceptor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nociceptor

Answer (score 1):

(a) What's being defined in your first paragraph is *internal energy*, not heat.
[Heat is energy *in transit* spontaneously from a region of high temperature to a region of low temperature.]

(b) Vigorously vibrating molecules transfer energy to our skin making its molecules vibrate more vigorously. Some of our nerve-endings transfer this information as an electrical signal via nerves to our brains, which generate a sensation of hotness. Is your sensation of hotness the same as mine? Is your sensation of redness the same as mine? I've no idea. I doubt if it will ever be possible to explain why we get exactly the sensation that we do when we touch something hot (or see something red). But we can of course use a thermometer to measure temperature.

(c) "Suppose I keep a body at a certain height it will surely possess potential energy but that energy need not make it move vigorously as in the case of molecules." A body's internal energy is energy possessed by its particles in the frame of reference of the body's centre of mass. So changing a body's height above the ground, or setting it moving won't change its internal energy. However, rubbing the object (doing frictional work) will make the molecules vibrate more vigorously about their mean positions, giving it more internal energy. So will supplying it with heat, for example by conduction through a solid: the vibrations are passed from atom to atom by the inter-atomic forces.

Comment: But sir why on giving energy the molecules start moving?

Comment: I want to know what is the relation between energy and rapid movement of particles

Comment: "why on giving energy the molecules start moving?" How else can molecules receive energy without vibrating? We're not pushing or pulling the body as a whole: changes in internal energy take place (by definition) without changing the position of the centre of mass of the body.

Comment: @Sagnik Dhar I've altered (c) in my answer, to try and make this more clear.

Answer (score 1):

> In the chapter calorimetry of class 10 I read that heat energy is the
> total energy content of a body, that is sum of the kinetic energy of
> the molecules and their potential energy due to the attractive forces
> between them.

That is totally wrong. The total energy content of a body is its internal energy, that is, the sum of its kinetic and potential energies at the microscopic  (atom/molecular level) energy.

Heat, in thermodynamics, is energy transfer between bodies due solely to a temperature difference between the bodies. Heat is not the energy of a body. That is properly called the internal energy of the body.

If you want to progress in thermodynamics it is absolutely essential that you know the difference between heat (energy transfer due to temperature difference) and internal energy (the energy content of a body at the microscopic level).

> But why is it that just because a couple of molecules are moving
> randomly and rapidly they need to be hot? I mean why they give a
> sensation of "HOTNESS" when it is touched.

The random motion of  molecules (i.e., the kinetic energy of the molecules), are reflected in the temperature of the substance. The sensation of "hotness" is the bodies sensation of the elevated temperature that the motion of  the molecules produces.

> What is actually the relation between rapid movement and becoming hot?

The rapid motion increases temperature. Increased temperature produces the sensation of "hot"

> Also why do the molecules vibrate on heating and the vibration
> increases on supplying more heat.

In the case of heat transfer by conduction and convection, supplying more heat (energy) can increase the kinetic energy of the molecules.Heat transfers kinetic energy from the higher temperature substance to the lower temperature substance by means of collisions between the atoms/molecules of the higher temperature substance (atoms/molecules of higher kinetic energy) to the lower temperature substance (atoms/molecules of lower kinetic energy). Depending on the energy levels, heat can increase vibrational, rotational, and or translational kinetic energy of the atoms/molecules.

> Suppose I keep a body at a certain height it will surely possess
> potential energy but that energy need not make it move vigorously as
> in the case of molecules.

The body at a certain height has gravitational potential energy with respect to that height. But that energy pertains to the totality of the molecules/atoms (total mass) of the body with respect to that height. That  has no effect on the movement of the atoms/molecules at the microscopic level (the intern kinetic/potential energy). The internal potential energy of the body relates to the forces between the molecules and atoms of the body, not gravity.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So sir can we say that the magnitude of  the average kinetic energy of the molecules is the magnitude of temperature of the body

Comment: We can say that temperature is a measure of the average translational kinetic energy of the molecules. If the average translational kinetic energy of the molecules of two objects is the same the temperature of the two objects will be the same and no heat transfer between the objects will occur.

Answer (score 0):

The question of why an increase of molecules kinetic energy gives us a heat sensation belongs to biology.

But it is not so obvious that the temperature of something is related to its kinetic molecular energy.

I think that one proof of that relation, and historically probably the most important, was the theory of the [brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion) by Einstein.

Before that connection, we could talk about energy in 2 separated realms: mechanical energy and thermal energy, that were interchangable but completely different.

After that, the mechanical concept of energy entered, so to speak, also in the thermal realm, through [statistical mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_mechanics).